# Installing PyMuPDF on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python-3.x, clang, apple-m1, macos-big-sur, pymupdf

I wanted to import fitz in my code. To do that, I tried installing PyMuPDF using

```
pip3 install PyMuPDF
```

However, this installation fails and returns this error:

```
fitz/fitz_wrap.c:2754:10: fatal error: 'fitz.h' file not found
#include <fitz.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/opt/homebrew/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

I also tried installing mupdf and mupdf-tools via Homebrew. None of them could fix this issue.
I would appreciate any help to fix this installation error!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming you are using M1 Mac, you can solve this problem installing `mupdf`, `swig`, `freetype` and latest version of PyMuPDF:

```
brew install mupdf swig freetype
pip install https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/archive/master.tar.gz
```

Source: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/discussions/875

Comment: Wow, this worked like a charm! I tried so many solutions posted online but nothing else worked except this one. Thank you so much!

Comment: Excellent! After the `brew install mupdf swig freetype`, doing `pip install --upgrade pymupdf` also worked well.

Comment: You save my day, works... thanks

Comment: I had to install `swig-python` as well: `sudo port install swig-python`, only after that the pip install worked

Answer (score 7):

The instructions provided by Juan Garcia worked until June 18th 2022 for me. There's a few workarounds.

### Solution #1

Install the `wheel` package using **pip** and `swig` + `freetype` using **homebrew**. PyMuPDF should build itself successfully when running `pip install pymupdf`. This takes about five minutes on a late model M1 MBP. This does not require the `mupdf` package installed via homebrew.

### Solution #2

If you're using homebrew you can downgrade to `1.19.x` with the following:

```
cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" && git checkout 457cb59a52ff7666dc146c1c480d2ea98d63564f;

# If you already have mupdf installed use `brew reinstall` instead of `brew install`
cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" && HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install mupdf;
cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" && git checkout master && brew pin mupdf;

brew install swig freetype;

pip install https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/archive/refs/tags/1.19.6.tar.gz;
```

For reference here is the Formula commit history: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/mupdf.rb

Comment: Can you please explain more Solution 1, how to do that. I am having err.